# iOS NSStream to PHP uploader?

Tags: php, ios, file-upload, nsstream

I'm working on uploading a large file to my server. I have the iOS code that sets up an input and output stream. I can see that it successfully uploads to my videoUploader.php file because I have it making a response with the temporary file size and location. However, it executes the code, or so it seems before it gets the rest of the file. I cannot find any where online a full example of the server side handling.

```
$upload_directory = 'uploads/';
$temp_file = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];
$filename = "testme.mp4";//basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
$target_location =  $upload_directory . $filename;
$size = $_FILES['uploaded']['size'];

move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $target_location);
```

All my files that it "moves" are 0 kb. It seems like there needs to be a way for me to tell php to wait until the temporary file is complete and then execute this code. I am an extreme novice at php, help please!